Approximate solution of ODE: Estimate error of the solution with polynom and the expression of the ODE

Consider the initial value problem
$$ \begin{cases} 
u'(t)=f(t,u(t))\\[10pt]
u(0)=u_0 \in \mathbb{R}
\end{cases} $$

Let's assume this initial value problem has a unique solution of the form
$$ u:[0,T]\to \mathbb{R}. $$
with $ T>0 $. Instead of considering the expression of the solution $ u $ I chose annother way by creating a taylor polynom $ p_n $ of $ u $ around the point $ 0 $ with order $ n\in \mathbb{N} $:
$$ \begin{align}
u^{(0)}(0)&=u_0,\\[10pt]
u^{(1)}(0)&=u'(0)=f(0,u(0)),\\[10pt]
u^{(2)}(0)&=\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}f(t,u^{(0)}(t)),\\[10pt]
\vdots\\[10pt]
u^{(n)}(0)&=\left.\frac{d^{n-1}}{d^{n-1}t}\right|_{t=0}f(t,u^{(0)}(t)).
\end{align} $$
Now I get the n-th taylor polynom
$$ p_n(t)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^n \frac{1}{k!}\cdot u^{(k)}(0)\cdot t^k $$
and I consider the error
$$ \varepsilon_n(t):=|p_n'(t)-f(t,p_n(t))| $$
on $ [0,T] $.
How can I estimate the new error
$$ E_n(t):=|u(t)-p_n(t)| $$
on $ [0,T] $ with $ \varepsilon_n $? The background is that you don't know/consider in general the expression of $ u $. Otherwise you could estimate $ E_n $ by some "classical" forms with the remainder term of the n-th taylor polynom of $ u $.
But you have indead the expression of $ f $ and $ p_n $ by calculating it's coefficient's iterative on point $ 0 $.

One example:
$$ \begin{cases} 
u'(t)=f(t,u(t))=\frac{1}{u(t)}\\[10pt]
u(0)=1
\end{cases} $$
has a unique solution
$$ u: \left[0,\frac{1}{2}\right]\to \mathbb{R}. $$
Taylor polynom of 2-th order around $ 0 $:
$$ \begin{align}
u^{(0)}(0)&=1,\\[10pt]
u^{(1)}(0)&=u'(0)=f(0,u(0))=\frac{1}{u(0)}=1,\\[10pt]
u^{(2)}(0)&=\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0}f(t,u^{(0)}(t))=\left.\frac{d}{dt}\right|_{t=0} \frac{1}{u(t)}=\left(\frac{-u'(t)}{u(t)^2}\right)_{t=0}=\frac{-u'(0)}{u(0)^2}=-1.
\end{align} $$
with
$$ p_2(t)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^2 \frac{1}{k!}\cdot u^{(k)}(0)\cdot t^k =1+t-\frac{1}{2}t^2. $$

